# How to delete last 10 records in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In Sqlite, can I know how to delete last 10 records? I've wrote following coding but seems not working at all.

```
delete from tb_news where newsid = (SELECT newsid from tb_news order by newsid asc limit 10)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
 delete from tb_news where newsid IN 
(SELECT newsid from tb_news order by newsid desc limit 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL statement to the below.

```
delete from tb_news where newsid IN (SELECT newsid from tb_news order by newsid DESC limit 20)
```

Side note:  sqllite may not support LIMIT in the sub query.

Comment: It should be DESC instead of ASC.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad I have corrected the answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried?

```
delete from tb_news where newsid IN (SELECT newsid from tb_news order by newsid asc limit 20)
```

I don't know your table structure, but maybe, it should be DESC instead of ASC. I mean DESC will give you the biggest IDs (and so, the latest).

Comment: It should be DESC instead of ASC.