# My code do not deleting last 2 rows from sqlite database table in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I am working on Android app In which I want to delete last two rows from sq-lite database table. If any one knows then please help.

I have implement a query which delete only last row

```
 String deleteQuerry= "DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='"
                    + project_id
                    + "' AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_chat)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat order by id desc limit 2)
```

Reference: [How to delete last 10 records in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738898/how-to-delete-last-10-records-in-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks For Help :)

Comment: anytime @Nancythakkar

Comment: when i move to the next activity then again back on this activity where i am using this query then it does not work why?

Comment: move the above code to resume method(one of the activity life cycle method),so that it will be called whenever the activity ia resumed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
"DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat order by id desc limit 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE  project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND id IN (
     SELECT id
     FROM my_chat
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 0, 2
)
```